# The best way to make a regex matching exactly zero characters in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

How to explicitly define a `regex` (numbered or named capturing group), which always matches exactly zero characters?

```perl6
> "abc" ~~ m/()abc/
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
Null regex not allowed

> my regex null {}
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
Null regex not allowed

> my regex null {<[]>}
regex null {<[]>}
> "abc" ~~ m/<null>abc/
False
```

Of course I can use something like the following, but I'm looking for an idiomatic way of doing it.

```perl6
> my regex null {a ** 0}
regex null {a ** 0}
> "abc" ~~ m/<null>abc/
｢abc｣
 null => ｢｣
```

UPD: This works, but is it the best way?

```perl6
> my regex null { '' }
regex null { '' }
> "abc" ~~ m/<null>abc/
｢abc｣
 null => ｢｣
> "abc" ~~ m/('') abc/
｢abc｣
 0 => ｢｣
```

Comment: Why can't you simply use `"abc" ~~ m/^^abc/`?

Comment: Because I want to have either named or numbered capture.

Comment: If there is nothing there, then you will always get a match. That is... there is always a collection of nothings before and after every string of characters. But, I guess I am missing some deeper interpretation?

Comment: Of course. But I need this zero `regex` to become a part of `match` object.

Comment: @PeterAbolins Please see the answer below: the thing I was looking for really exists in Perl 6. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The assertion that always succeeds and matches 0 characters is: `<?>`.

For example:

```
say so 'foo' ~~ / <?> 'foo' /;
# output: True
```

As raiph pointed out, the corresponding negative version, which always fails, is `<!>`. I've used this to insert error messages when part of a parse should not be reached if the input is valid. That section of the regex might read:

```
\d || [ { note "Error: the previous token must be followed by a number."; } <!> ]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, and it works flawlessly. Can you explain the syntax? Why does `<?>` match zero?

Comment: @EugeneBarsky `< ... >` is the syntax for assertions. An assertion can match any number of characters, or none. As far as I know, this is just a special case. It's not a hack based on some special interpretation of `?`. It just means match 0 characters successfully.

Comment: Anyway, it's a great solution. (I was thinking it means smth like `''?`, i.e. zero or one occasion of an empty string)

Comment: I think needing to match 0 characters is more common than you think. I ended up doing this when I was writing some code to parse Unity 3D's almost-YAML data format. I used it for `||` matching where matching nothing was an option, but I can't remember why `?` was unsuitable for that scenario.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky Nah, it's not trying to optionally match something. This is mentioned in the docs, but the explanation isn't great: https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes

Comment: My question is not abstract, I'm making first parsers to analyze my data, and I really need this type of assertion.

Comment: Maybe it's of the same type as look-around assertions? A type of look-around with zero-condition.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky It's sorta like `''?` but much simpler/faster. `< something-goes-here >` is an assertion. There are many different forms of assertion but all follow the same logic. If an assertion is True, matching continues. If False, matching stops (or backtracks). Some assertions consume some of the input (if they are True). Others do not (in which case they're called zero-width assertions). `<?>` and `<!>` are the simplest of these zero width assertions. Neither does any processing of the input. Neither consumes any input. `<?>` returns True, `<!>` returns False. Aiui it's as simple as that.